# Skipping one item in the column

Tags: sql-server-2005, asp-classic

I created a simple news website. I store both videos and images in IMAGES table. Videos added have videos and images added have images stored in a column called ImagesType. Images and Videos attached to a news is stored in ImagesID column of the NEWS table. My problem occurs when I need to display the first image of a news.

i.e.
IMAGES table:

```
ImagesID ImagesLgURL                        ImagesType  
1        /FLPM/media/videos/0H7T9C0F.flv    videos     
2     /FLPM/media/images/8R5D7M8O.jpg    images  
3        /FLPM/media/images/0E7Q9Z0C.jpg    images  

NEWS table  
NewsID   ImagesID  NewsTitle  
1        1;2;      Street Chic: Paris            ERROR     
2        3;        Paris Runway                  NO ERROR
```

The following code give me an error with the 2nd news item because the first ImageID stored in the list is not an image but a video. I need to figure out a way to skip the video item and display the next image.

I hope I made sense.

```
SQL = "SELECT NEWSID, CATEGORIESID, IMAGESID, NEWSTITLE, NEWSSHORTDESC, NEWSACTIVE, NEWSDATEENTERED"
SQL = SQL & " FROM NEWS N"
SQL = SQL & " WHERE NEWSACTIVE = 1"
SQL = SQL & " ORDER BY NEWSDATEENTERED DESC"
Set objNews = objConn.Execute(SQL)

Do While intLooper1 <= 3 And Not objNews.EOF 

IMAGES =   Split(Left(objNews("IMAGESID"),Len(objNews("IMAGESID"))-1), ";") 

SQL = "SELECT ImagesID, ImagesName, ImagesLgURL, ImagesSmURL, ImagesType"
SQL = SQL & " FROM IMAGES I"
SQL = SQL & " WHERE ImagesID = " & IMAGES(0) & " AND ImagesType = 'images'"
Set objLgImage = objConn.Execute(SQL)

<div>
<a href="?Section=news&SubSection=redirect&NEWSID=<%=objNews("NEWSID")%>">
<img src="<%=objLgImage("ImagesLgURL")%>" alt="<%=objLgImage("ImagesName")%>"  />
</a>
</div>
<%
    objLgImage.Close
    Set objLgImage = Nothing

    intLooper1 = intLooper1 + 1
    objNews.MoveNext 
    Loop
%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have the NewsID in the images Table and put a ForeingKey on it

```
**NEWS table**
NewsID   NewsTitle  
----------------------------
1        Street Chic: Paris            
2        Paris Runway    

**Images table**
ImageID (PK)  NewsID (FK) ImagesLgURL                        ImagesType  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1             1           /FLPM/media/videos/0H7T9C0F.flv    videos     
2             1           /FLPM/media/images/8R5D7M8O.jpg    images  
3             2           /FLPM/media/images/0E7Q9Z0C.jpg    images
```

Then you can easily select the first photo of each news

```
SQL = "SELECT NEWSID, CATEGORIESID, NEWSTITLE, NEWSSHORTDESC, NEWSACTIVE,"     
SQL = SQL & " NEWSDATEENTERED,"
SQL = SQL & " (SELECT TOP 1 ImageID from Images where Images.NewsID = N.NewsID 
                 AND Images.ImageType = 'Images') as ImageID"
SQL = SQL & " FROM NEWS N"
SQL = SQL & " WHERE NEWSACTIVE = 1"
SQL = SQL & " ORDER BY NEWSDATEENTERED DESC"
Set objNews = objConn.Execute(SQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should have a Video table and an Images table. That would be a much better design and it would solve your problem in a much cleaner solution.

Comment: Perhaps,  but if many of the columns are the same between the two types it might better to simply rename the table to something like "media".